# relation between conditional probability of subset and set

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, causality, subset

Suppose $A\subseteq B $. Can we derive a relationship between P(X|A) and P(X|B) for some X? X is associated with A.

Comment: What do you mean by $X$ is associated with $A$? It gets one value when $A$ and another when $A^{c}$?

Comment: Means $P(X|A) \neq p(A)$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without assuming anything else on $A, B$, and $X$, we have

$$P(X\mid A) = \frac{P(X, A)}{P(A)} \le \frac{P(X,B)P(B)}{P(A)P(B)} = \frac{P(B)}{P(A)} P(X \mid B)$$